# SQL Dependency C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Как заставить работать?
Взял пример с msdn, вставил в свою формочку:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SqlDependency.Start(conString);            
        }
        string conString = @"SERVER=alex\srv; DATABASE=myBase; Trusted_Connection=True;";
        SqlConnection connection;
        void SomeMethod()
        {
            // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.
            connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
            connection.Open();
            // Create a new SqlCommand object.
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT Id, Number FROM dbo.ProductionTask",
                connection))
            {

                // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                // Maintain the reference in a class member.

                // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
                dependency.OnChange += new
                   OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

                // Execute the command.
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            tb1.Text += $"\r\n {reader.GetInt32(0)} - {reader.GetString(1)}";
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }

        }
        // Handler method
        void OnDependencyChange(object sender,
           SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text += $"\r\n {e.Info.ToString()}";
        }
        void Termination()
        {
            connection.Close();
            SqlDependency.Stop(conString);
        }

        private void sqlStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SomeMethod();
        }

        private void sqlStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Termination();
        }
    }
}
```

не работает. Я меняю поле в базе данных, но уведомление не приходит.
Брокер включен в базе данных. Исключений нет
Куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась, когда я поменял в SQL Server database owner на SA. Не понимаю, почему это имеет значение?